# Removing \" from string with cat()

Tags: r, string

I can't understand why **#3** doesn't give me `xxx"yyy`.

`xxx\\\"yyy" %>% cat()` results in `xxx\"yyy` which is input of **#2**. I would expect that the second `cat()` in **#3** would give the same result as running **#2**.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#1
"xxx\"yyy"
#> [1] "xxx\"yyy"

#2
"xxx\"yyy" %>% cat()
#> xxx"yyy

#3
"xxx\\\"yyy" %>% cat() %>% cat()
#> xxx\"yyy
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I got stuck with that when loading a text file with readr's `read_file()` which converts `\"\", \"SQL\"` in file to `\\\"\\\", \\\"SQL\\\"` in string.

I would like to get string with `"", "SQL"`.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't understand why #3 doesn't give me `xxx"yyy`.

In a nutshell, because `… %>% cat() %>% cat()` makes no sense. `cat()` has no return value. It writes the result *to a file* (which might be an output stream).

So there’s no value to be piped into the second `cat()` invocation argument list. Remember that `a %>% b()` is just a different way of writing `b(a)`. You’re executing `cat(cat(…))`.

If you want to unescape a string, don’t use `cat()`. Use `sub()` or `str_replace()` from ‘stringr’. Though if you’re depending on ‘stringr’ anyway you might find it more convenient to use the function `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode`, which does exactly that, and ‘stringi’ is imported by ‘stringr’ anyway (so it’s not an additional dependency).

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
cat('xxx"yyy', '\n')
 #xxx"yyy
```

Or pass it as an `r'` string literally without the need to escape anything

```
r"{xxx"yyy"}" %>%
    cat
#xxx"yyy"
```